Visual Studio 2022 yellow highlight while typing code
Ever since the last update, Visual Studio sometimes highlights some code I type in yellow. See the attached screenshot.
Any idea what this is?
I can't really reproduce it, it happens only sometimes, let's say once a day. The highlight goes away when I hit the escape key, not sure if anything else makes it go away too because it happens so rarely and I wasn't paying too much attention until now.
Current version of my VS is 17.12.3, community edition.


Update:
It's not a search result. This is how searching inside a document looks like:

--
Update 2:
Search results look different when you deselect them, but still different from the weird yellow highlight.


This looks like the highlight of a search result (Ctrl+F). Any extensions you have installed?

@GSerg Good guess, but it looks different. See the edit. I don't have any extensions installed AFAIK. And it keeps highlighting as I type. It was yellow when I typed in the first 'c', then the highlight kept following as I was typing the rest of the line.

The closest in the color schema is the "code snippet field", are you pressing any hotkeys related to that?

@GSerg Never used them. I just tried the two hotkeys I seem to have defined for them and they make popups, don't highlight anything.
